# CSS Animation not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Some insight into the project:
A full interactive website, where animations will play.. then they'll stop, once they've stopped and a mouseover event on an animation occurs it will play until 70% of the animation is complete, when clicking on another object (in this case text) it will complete it's cycle.

My project partner made the animation in Google web designer, we've tried multiple programs for our project such as Adobe Edge, but unfortunately due to the size of our animations we are unable to use SVG or PNG sequences, and the same goes for spritesheets.. so we arrived at css animations, unfortunately my knowledge of css animations is quite limited and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out.

I have a problem: why doesn't my CSS animation act the same in Chrome as in Firefox?

I've tried the following solutions and looked at the following posts:

1. [css3 animation not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265096/css3-animation-not-working-in-chrome)
2. [CSS Animation not working on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939736/css-animation-not-working-on-chrome)
3. [Chrome Keyframe animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003675/chrome-keyframe-animation-not-working)

jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('.gwd-img-r1sa').toggle(function () {
    //    $('.gwd-img-r1sa').css({"animation-play-state":"paused","-webkit-animation-play-state":"paused"});
    //}, function () {
    //    $('.gwd-img-r1sa').css({"animation-play-state":"running","-webkit-animation-play-state":"running"});
    //});

    $(".gwd-img-r1sa").on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(".gwd-img-r1sa").css({"animation-iteration-count":"0.7", "-webkit-animation-iteration-count":"0.9"});
    });

    $("#play").on("click", function(){
        $(".gwd-img-r1sa").css({"animation-iteration-count":"1", "-webkit-animation-iteration-count":"1"});
    });

});

</script>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css">

    /**.gwd-img-r1sa:hover, .gwd-img-r1sa:focus
{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
**/

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-perspective: 1400px;
  -moz-perspective: 1400px;
  perspective: 1400px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.gwd-img-r1sa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 192px;
  height: 146px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  left: 312px;
  top: 604px;
  -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes gwd-empty-animation {
  0% { opacity: 0.001; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes gwd-empty-animation {
  0% { opacity: 0.001; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes gwd-empty-animation {
  0% { opacity: 0.001; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
  0% { left: 312px; top: 604px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  30% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  50% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.0510417556, 0.9986965201, 0, 0, -0.9986965201, 0.0510417556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;}
  100% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.051, 0.9987, 0, 0, -0.9987, 0.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 312, 146, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
}
@-moz-keyframes gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
  0% { left: 312px; top: 604px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  30% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  50% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.0510417556, 0.9986965201, 0, 0, -0.9986965201, 0.0510417556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  100% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.051, 0.9987, 0, 0, -0.9987, 0.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 312, 146, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
}
@keyframes gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
  0% { left: 312px; top: 604px; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
  30% { left: 595px; top: 350px; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
  50% { left: 595px; top: 350px; transform: matrix3d(0.0510417556, 0.9986965201, 0, 0, -0.9986965201, 0.0510417556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
  100% { left: 595px; top: 350px; transform: matrix3d(0.051, 0.9987, 0, 0, -0.9987, 0.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 312, 146, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
}
body .gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation {
  -webkit-animation: gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
  -moz-animation: gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

</style>
```

html:

```
    <img src="3ds_preset_gearshape.png" class="gwd-img-r1sa gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation" data-gwd-style="" data-gwd-override-style="" style="animation-iteration-count: 0.1;">


<div id="play">
    click here to play
</div>
```

Can someone please help?

Also: Why does the image move, then stop.. then on hover it sometimes skips to 30% instead of playing until 30%? the same goes for skipping to 70% instead of playing until 70%?

Just found something that could be note worthy:

Changing: `<img src="3ds_preset_gearshape.png" class="gwd-img-r1sa gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation" data-gwd-style="" data-gwd-override-style="" style="animation-iteration-count: 0.1;">`

to this: `<img src="3ds_preset_gearshape.png" class="gwd-img-r1sa gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation" data-gwd-style="" data-gwd-override-style="" style="-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0.1;">`

causes this bit of the animation to work in Chrome, but why didn't it work when I had this in the styles segment of my document?

Comment: I made [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvq6ee8d/) and (as far as i can tell) it's working?

Comment: @MrCoder fiddle works for me too

Comment: A couple of things could be the underlying issue. You are using jQuery to translate CSS transitions, and also CSS transitions. I would move your jQuery function into the CSS something like this .gwd-img-r1sa:hover Also its odd that you are using a decimal for an iteration count, as well as assigning it twice

Comment: My apologies, I should've phrased my question differently, why doesn't it act like it does in Firefox.. it runs, until 30% then skips on mouseenter to 70%? I have editted my question accordingly, I've assigned it twice because it doesn't work if I assign it within the <styles> tag, it only works if I assign it within the image

edit: i've the first assignment within the <styles> tag

Comment: unfortunately the following as suggested by Justin Medas doesn't work: .gwd-img-r1sa:hover in combination with animation-iteration-count: 0.7; when declaring -webkit- first and then -moz-

Comment: I am using a decimal for an iteration count because I would like the animation to stop at that point, then on hover play from that point until 0.7 (70%).. unless someone knows a different way to play only parts of an css animation?

Comment: Hey, chrome uses webkit, so you should change the iteration count in your jQuery code to 0.7, not 0.9.

Comment: I am currently using -webkit- and the iteration count is only supposed to make it play 70% of the animation, changing it to 90% is supposed to make it play 90% of the animation, however it always plays the same part of the animation, regardless of the value i've given to the iteration count, edit: i've changed the iteration count from 0.9 to 0.7 and it didn't change a thing, it still won't stop in google chrome and it doesn't stop at a different point in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: Your jQuery has a mistake in it. Change the `-webkit-animation-iteration-count` from 0.9 to 0.7. Also, please take a look at: http://caniuse.com/#search=animation. You can see, that you have to use the prefix "-webkit" for google chrome. That is why, you need to define both of it in your img style tag. Like so:

```
<img src="3ds_preset_gearshape.png" class="gwd-img-r1sa gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation" data-gwd-style="" data-gwd-override-style="" style="animation-iteration-count: 0.1;-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 0.1;">
```

A better way to do this, would be to define the iteration count in your stylesheet, not in the html. If you need different iteration counts for different img's, then this is not a good solution for you, ofcourse. Otherwise change:

```
3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards
```

to

```
3s linear 0s 0.1 normal forwards
```

And leave the `style` in the img tags blank

For the stop and play part of your question:

[jsfiddle.net/Lvq6ee8d/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvq6ee8d/14/)

For explanation: You know that your animation runs 3 seconds, so I have set a timeout function, which starts when the event "animationstart" is being triggered. Then after 300ms(3000ms/100*10 = 300ms) the animationplaystate is set to pause. So after 10%, the animation stops. And on hover, the animation continues. Also keep in mind, that in this example we need to change the css a little bit. We set the animation iteration to the desired amount, where we want the animation to be when it's finished(1 in my example), so we can use pause and running on it.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't quite work :( neither does it input into the console 'Hallo' @Frederik

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, I just got off my internship, it appears to be working in jsfiddle, I'll try to implement the code tomorrow and will post a reply as soon as i've done so, thank you for all your help! :D

Comment: No Problem, tell me if you got further problems

Comment: I saw that you include the Bootstrap 3.0.2 and 2.3.2 may I ask why you included two different versions? and is this framework loyalty free? If so which document do I need to refer to as source? 'Gruntfile.js'? or a different one?

Comment: i've tried to include the jquery 2.1.0 library and i've linked the files i had to according to a website, however it still doesn't work

Comment: You have to be more explicit. What exactly doesn't work? Does the console fire an error?

Comment: My apologies, the mouseenter event doesn't work, I've tried replacing mouseenter by mouseover, thinking it could be a Jquery bug but this won't work either, I've replaced the animation with an alert('fire'); and this does work, so jquery does detect the mouseover and mouseenter function, it just won't play the animation on mouseenter/over

Comment: I've just tested it in Chrome, and the animation doesn't stop running after 10% of the animation

Comment: Ah. You have to put the .js in your head and then use $(function(){your whole js content here});. This will wait for the document to be ready.

Comment: I'll take screenshot and show you how my header looks: http://gyazo.com/f7739dba5b53f20c1320e501076306fb as you can see, my js code is under my js include for the lib and it's in the header, just above the styles tag edit: changing document.ready to  $(function(){ doesn't work either

Comment: do you have this page online? then it would be best if you could send me the link so i cant test it live

Comment: how can I send you the link, can I pm you in stackoverflow?

Comment: I've just uploaded it to a server.. in google chrome it runs, but doesn't stop.. however in firefox it doesn't even move...

Comment: The JSfiddle now works, but in firefox it does not.. i've added -moz- to the attribute changes in the js code.. but that didn't fix it. i've updated the files on the server, so that you may view them online

Comment: I have the link, but there is no javascript in there.

Comment: if you inspect element in chrome -> head -> script (near the bottom) it should be there I can see it

Comment: Im looking at the test.html, and there is definetly no script.

Comment: Sir, I've previously stated, that i've accidently linked the wrong file, as there are 3 html files my project partner created, it works in chrome but doesn't in firefox

Comment: Do you have any other means to talk, for example skype? it would be easier to explain that way

Comment: Can't see where u stated this :P. Anyways, I will look into this later.

Comment: Alright thank you for your help so far.. I got it to work in everything except for the fact that in Firefox it doesn't work at all, not even when i add in -moz-